# How to insert one key and multiple value in multimap c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem using map.

I used multi map to have one key with multiple value to solve this problem. However, it does not work. I think the problem is when I insert elements into multimap, but I cannot find anything wrong with that code. 
Here is the instruction: You will be given two words and a mapping between characters. Your task is to write a function that will check if the first word can be translated into the second word. You need to use the character mappings to decipher the first word and see if it matches the second. The character mappings can be applied repeatedly to each character.

Thank you!!

```
int checkmatch(char x, char y, std::multimap<char,char>mapp){
   if (x == y) return 1;
   while (mapp.find(x) != mapp.end()){
      if(mapp.find(x)->second==y)
         return 1;
      else
         x=mapp.find(x)->second;
      }   
      return 0;
}

bool wordsMatch( std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> & mappings, std::string leftWord, std::string rightWord ){
   // Your code goes here
   std::multimap<char,char> mapp;
   std::vector<char>value;
   int n=mappings.size();
   int result=0;
   char p1[leftWord.length()], p2[rightWord.length()];
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      mapp.insert(std::pair<char,char>(mappings[i].first, mappings[i].second));  
   }
   if (leftWord.length() != rightWord.length()){
      return false;}

   for(int i=0; i<leftWord.length();i++){
      p1[i]=leftWord[i];
      p2[i]=rightWord[i];}
   for(int i=0; i<leftWord.length();i++){
      result +=checkmatch(p1[i],p2[i], mapp);  
   }
   if (result == leftWord.length())
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Comment: "However, it does not work." my telepathy machine is broken today, please describe what that means

Comment: I used multimap to store the key and value. When I called it from another function, it does not include the second value of the key. Like, it supposed to have c-t, and c-e. But it only has c-t
Thank you!

Comment: @PhuNguyen The code you showed us has only one function. Please, create a [complete minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that generates your problem.

Comment: I just edited, please take a look.

Comment: You pass `mmap` to `checkmatch` **by value**, therefore, in this function, you effectively work with a copy of `mmap` from `wordsMatch`. Pass it **by reference** instead. The same holds for `x` — you assign it inside `checkmatch`, but this assignment has zero effect (it is not propagated outside of this function).